# Python "append" function

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, append

I'm having problems with adding accounts to mapping with function append.

```
mapp = ["example"]

example1 = raw_input("Enter Username: ")
if example1 in mapp:
    print "yay"
else:
    print ("Forgot Username eh?")
    example = raw_input("Enter New Username: ")
    if example not in mapp:
        mapp.append(sana)
```

So as you can see from the script, if i enter username "example", program prints "yay".
And if i type wrong i can create new "account" what i can use next time when i want my program to print "yay". But when i try to add new "account" it doesn't work. I don't get any error messages or anything but it just doesn't add new "account" to mapp. So any ideas ?

Comment: Where is the variable `sana` defined?

Answer (score 3):

You are not appending the right variable to `mapp`; you are appending `sana` but you should have appended `example` instead:

```
if example not in mapp:
    mapp.append(example)
```

For this use-case, you could use a `set` instead:

```
mapp = {'example'}

# ...
if example1 in mapp:
    # ...
else:
    # ... 
    example = raw_input("Enter New Username: ")
    mapp.add(example)
```

Comment: I fixed that. But now it's giving me an error "set object has no attribute 'append'" Can you still help me ? Thanks